# Throwing an exception knowing only the name?

Tags: c#, exception

If I have a C# `List<string>` of exception names (eg. InternalServerErrorException, ConflictException, etc), how would I go about instantiating and throwing the specific exception with nothing more than the string value?

To clarify, I have a simple name as a string pulled from another source, eg. "ConflictException".  I need to be able to throw that specific exception.

```
string myException = "ConflictException";
```

I cannot just do a `throw new myException` without first casting (or otherwise converting) to an actual Exception() type.  I have tried to do a safe cast, but it cannot convert string to Exception.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond `throw CreateInstanceByClassNameAsManySoPostShow(className)`? Clarification on where you are stuck would make it easier to provide specific help.

Comment: I am sorry you were confused.  I have updated my question.  Thanks

Comment: Why would you want your code to throw dynamically computed exceptions?  That's such a bizzarre thing to want to do, I'd love to know what your use case is that has sent you down this path.

Comment: I agree it's odd but since you asked.. the use case is to allow users to define a range of matching criteria in a response from a remote system.  If the criteria matches, then throw the configured exception.  It's an attempt to be flexible based on a multiple of possible and changing responses that are parsed from a remote system.

Comment: Seems like the exception message should be the configurable part, not the exception type.  Also, what happens if there is a configured exception type but that type does not actually exist?

Comment: Why not throw your own custom exception, and add the original exception name as value or as exception message? e.g. `throw new MyRemoteSystemException(myException)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't.

You can't because:

- Exceptions in your list might not be loaded in your current app domain, which could make them impossible to load
- Exceptions don't have a consistent constructor signature, making it error prone to create them using reflection. Although most exception types contain a `ctor(string)`, not all of them do.

You can try something like this, but keep in mind that it is error prone:

```
// Load all exceptions once and map their name to their type
var exceptions = (
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in assembly.GetTypes()
    where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Exception))
    where !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    group type by type.Name into g
    select g)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.First());

// Later on, load a type by its name
string myException = "ConflictException";

Type exceptionType = exceptions[myException];

// Create a new instance, assuming it has a ctor(string)
Exception exception = (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(
    exceptionType, new object[] { "Some message" });

// throw the exception
throw exception;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was genuinely concerned this was the case as it's a design from another that I'm trying to implement.  Going the reflection route is probably going to force some redesign.  I appreciate your response.  Thanks